# What is the location for pg_upgrade_dump log file?

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgresql-14, pg-upgrade

I am trying to run a pg_upgrade on my existing 12.8 postgres and migrate it to 14.3 with docker based installation. I got the below error :

```
Performing Upgrade
------------------
Analyzing all rows in the new cluster                       ok
Freezing all rows in the new cluster                        ok
Deleting files from new pg_xact                             ok
Copying old pg_xact to new server                           ok
Setting oldest XID for new cluster                          ok
Setting next transaction ID and epoch for new cluster       ok
Deleting files from new pg_multixact/offsets                ok
Copying old pg_multixact/offsets to new server              ok
Deleting files from new pg_multixact/members                ok
Copying old pg_multixact/members to new server              ok
Setting next multixact ID and offset for new cluster        ok
Resetting WAL archives                                      ok
Setting frozenxid and minmxid counters in new cluster       ok
Restoring global objects in the new cluster                 ok
Restoring database schemas in the new cluster
  template1
  myschema

*failure*

Consult the last few lines of "pg_upgrade_dump_1.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.
```

Can anyone help me with the location of `pg_upgrade_dump_1.log` and `pg_upgrade_internal.log` files?

Comment: I think it's in the "current directory" (i.e. the one that was current when you started `pg_upgrade`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the user a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in his comment logs are created in the location where you executed pg_upgrade.

Several files are created like logs dumps and others.